# Why is my refrigerator tripping a specific (brand new & tested) GFCI in my kitchen but not the other GFCI when I plug it in on another circuit?

Tags: wiring, gfci, refrigerator

Been troubleshooting this for a week now.  After 3 years working perfectly (age of fridge) I noticed the fridge had no power last weekend.  The GFCI had tripped on one of two circuits that power my kitchen.  I reset it and it tripped again instantly.  I got a 12ga extension cord and plugged it into the other gfci protected circuit and it has been working fine.  The troubled circuit consists of the line from the breaker to a to a 20a gfci and then runs to two consecutive standard outlets.  The fridge is the only device plugged into the circuit.  I replaced the gfci and instead of tripping instantly, it now trips every 5 to 10 minutes.  Seems to coincide with the cooling or defrost cycle.  Tested the fridge on several other gfci protected circuits in the house with no issue.  Testing each of the 3 outlets on my troubled circuit shows no faults and I checked all the wiring I can see.  I’m out of ideas!

Comment: GFCIs and fridges sometimes do not work together.  It is usually recommended not to have a fridge on a GFCI protected circuit.  It might be a problem  with the fridge, a problem with the circuit(maybe hidden in walls), or the GFCI just does not like fridges.

Comment: When it comes to fridges and GFCIs, sometimes you get lucky, sometimes you don't, and sometimes your luck changes for no apparent reason, maybe humidity, sunspots, planetary alignment, etc...

Comment: Thanks.  For me it’s now more about the mystery then what I am going to do about it.  I.e. Run a new dedicated circuit.  Sounds like I should just chalk it up to gods will.  Bet I still cut the wall open.  I hate mysteries.

Comment: I am sure that some electricians will have better/more sensitive testers that most DIYers cannot afford for testing this problem and could find if there is a problem.  Away from water/sinks, usually a dedicated circuit is maybe cheaper.

Comment: I had the same issue last week, here's what I did about it: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/268612/avoiding-gfci-for-my-fridge

Comment: GFCI name could be misleading. A GFCI actually measures current unbalance flow between hot and neutral and it calls it ground fault if it is unbalanced

Answer (score 2):

As per code:

GFCI protection is only required for kitchen receptacles that serve the countertop surfaces. There's no requirement to GFCI protect receptacles that serve a refrigerator. Unless the fridge is plugged into a countertop receptacle.

**Why does the Fridge trips the GFCI?**

Any inductive load when switched off, can produce electromagnetic interference (EMI). This interference can, and often does, trip GFCI devices. Fridge compressors have a few inductive loads, that could cause the trip. To prevent that most modern frige have EMI filter.

Answer (score 2):

As far as a fix, dedicated circuit is not, technically, the solution. You can have the refrigerator on a circuit that is part of the rest of the kitchen, just make it *not* be GFCI protected. The key - dedicated or not - is to place the receptacle in a location where (a) it is more than 6' from the edge of any sink and (b) not in a position to serve the counter.

Arguably, putting the receptacle behind the refrigerator designates it as "not for the counter", but using a *single* receptacle instead of a typical duplex receptacle will make it 100% clear. A single receptacle may cost more than a duplex, but don't worry because (a) the cost is still very low (at Home Depot currently < $4 for a Leviton) and (b) they are usually good quality (e.g., "Commercial Grade").

As far as dedicated or not, if you are using (as in the original post) GFCI/receptacle rather than GFCI/breaker, simply pigtail the wires for the single refrigerator receptacle off of the *LINE* side of a GFCI/receptacle rather than the *LOAD* side and you're all set.

Note that if this is a dedicated circuit with a single receptacle then if it is a 20A circuit then it must be a 20A receptacle. A 20A circuit with multiple receptacles (even just one duplex receptacle) can use all 15A, all 20A or a mixture. Kitchen circuits serving the *countertop* receptacles must be 20A, so if it is not dedicated and the other receptacles are countertop receptacles then it must be a 20A circuit. If it is dedicated then I see no reason it couldn't be 15A instead of 20A - same price breaker, but save a little using 14 AWG wire.

Answer (score 0):

Because the outlets are just a little bit different.

Fridges shouldn't be on a GFCI circuit, for exactly the reason you're experiencing.